# SQLException: no such table: main.[]: CREATE INDEX

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I just reset my database with rake `db:reset`

I have 3 tables in my models folder: Performer table, Performance table and a relationship table between the two PerformerPerformance.

When i run the `db:migrate` I get error that the table does not exist

```
-- add_index(:performer_performances, :performer_id)
-- add_index(:performer_performances, :performer_id)
rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.performer_performances: CREATE  INDEX
 "index_performer_performances_on_performer_id" ON "performer_performances" ("pe
rformer_id")
C:/rubyProjects/dads/db/migrate/20140315155732_create_performer_performances.rb:
9:in `<class:CreatePerformerPerformances>'
C:/rubyProjects/dads/db/migrate/20140315155732_create_performer_performances.rb:
1:in `<top (required)>'
C:131071:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace) #ill include output with trace at the end
```

Here is my CreatePerformerPerformances migration file:

```
class CreatePerformerPerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :performer_performances do |t|
      t.integer :performer_id
      t.integer :performance_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
    add_index :performer_performances, :performer_id
    add_index :performer_performances, :performance_id
    add_index :performer_performances, [:performer_id, :performance_id], unique: true
end
```

my PerformerPerformance model

```
class PerformerPerformance < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :performer
  belongs_to :performance
  validates :performer_id, presence: true
  validates :performance_id, presence: true
end
```

performer model

```
class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
   has_many :performer_performances, dependent: :destroy  
   has_many :performances, through: :performer_performances

   def part_of?(performance) 
     performer_performances.find_by(performance_id: performance.id)
   end

   def perform_in!(performance)
      performer_performances.create!(performance_id: performance.id)
   end

end
```

Performance model:

```
class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :date, length: { maximum: 30 }  
   validates :location, length: { maximum: 60 }
   has_many :performer_performances, dependent: :destroy  
   has_many :performers, through: :performer_performances

   def has_performer?(performer) 
     performer_performances.find_by(performer_id: performer.id)
   end

   def include! (performer)
     performer_performances.create!(performer_id: performer.id)
   end

end
```

Here is the migration with trace:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
-- add_index(:performer_performances, :performer_id)
-- add_index(:performer_performances, :performer_id)
rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.performer_performances: CREATE  INDEX
 "index_performer_performances_on_performer_id" ON "performer_performances" ("pe
rformer_id")
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/databa
se.rb:91:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/databa
se.rb:91:in `new'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/databa
se.rb:91:in `prepare'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/databa
se.rb:134:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notif
ications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:522:in `add_index'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:625:in `block in method_missing'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:597:in `block in say_with_time'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:597:in `say_with_time'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:617:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:383:in `method_missing'
C:/rubyProjects/dads/db/migrate/20140315155732_create_performer_performances.rb:
9:in `<class:CreatePerformerPerformances>'
C:/rubyProjects/dads/db/migrate/20140315155732_create_performer_performances.rb:
1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/depen
dencies.rb:229:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/depen
dencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/depen
dencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/depen
dencies.rb:229:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:718:in `load_migration'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:714:in `migration'
C:131071:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:1012:in `use_transaction?'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:922:in `rescue in block in migrate'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:919:in `block in migrate'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:916:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:916:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:764:in `up'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:742:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railtie
s/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block i
n execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute
'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block i
n invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_
with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'

C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `
invoke_task'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
block in top_level'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `
run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `
top_level'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `b
lock in run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `
standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `r
un'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>
'
C:/Ruby200/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby200/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I know I probably edited some file which is causing the error but i have no idea where to look. If you need additional information or files pls ask and ill post them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have all the migration functions inside `change` method

```
class CreatePerformerPerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    create_table :performer_performances do |t|
      t.integer :performer_id
      t.integer :performance_id
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :performer_performances, :performer_id
    add_index :performer_performances, :performance_id
    add_index :performer_performances, [:performer_id, :performance_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much notepadd++ has an option to move things if you hold shift+ctrl and press up arrows I must have done that. Now i only have a problem that my index name is too long but i think ill be able to fix that

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  Consider RubyMine.  It is worth it.